# can't apply partial context to unlabeled file `pre-commit'

Tags: pre-commit-hook, selinux

I am getting this error when trying to modify the SELinux label on a pre-commit hook. 
My first try was

```
chcon -t httpd_exec_t pre-commit
```

Then I tried by adding the full context to the command

```
chcon -u unconfined_u -r object_r -t httpd_exec_t pre-commit
```

But got the same error. Checking the labels I figured out that it doesn't have the SELinux label at all. The ls -Z command returns the following

```
-rwxr-x--x apache apache ? pre-commit
```

Notice the ? symbol it should look something like this

```
-rwxr-x--x apache apache unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_exec_t:s0 pre-commit
```

I think that the error makes sense since the file does't have the SELinux label for some reason, the question is why and how to solve this.

I tried to restore the default SELinux context with the "restorecon -R -v /hooks" command but it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Please add the output of `matchpathcon /path/to/pre-commit` to your question, please.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
chcon -R -h unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_exec_t:s0 pre-commit
```